# MySQL Workbench table not refreshing

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I tried in MySQL Workbench to forward engineer a model, and when I did something went wrong with one of my schemas. The schema in the picture has a refresh icon on it, and the tables show it is refreshing but not actually pulling up the tables.

The tables are there and I am able to pull the data, but not sure how to undo this so I can see the tables in the tables tab.

Any idea?

[image: **The Tables are just showing refershing**]

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I got your actual problem. You triggered a refresh of your schema list and that never finishes. Is that correct? If so then you probably hit a bug. Are you using the latest MySQL Workbench version? Try restarting the application, which should workaround this temporary hickup.

Comment: The issue came when I started to do a forward engineering. This table started to just fetching. I have tried refreshing the application, and this is also showing the same on other computers.